# Exporting mapbox maps into pdf using phantomjs doesnt load featurelayer and geoJson layer

Tags: phantomjs, mapbox

I am using mapbox v1.6.1 
to show up

```
var mapboxMap = L.mapbox.map(mapName, 'examples.map-20v6611k',{tileLayer:{noWrap:true},zoomControl:false,zoomAnimation:false,fadeAnimation:false,inertia:false}).setView([23.8, -11], 1);
```

1. a choropleth map and

   var statesLayer = L.geoJson(localData,  {
                    style: getStyle,
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(mapboxMap);
2. a normal map with markers

   var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(mapPlotData).addTo(mapboxMap);

These two layers are not showing up when i export the webpage to pdf using phantomJS

Increasing the timeout doesnt work as well.

I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: any specific reason why you are not using the up to date mapbox lib(2.1.9)? Could possibly have a part in this..

Comment: With the latest mapbox lib(2.1.9) also i face the same issue.